# converting multiple rows to columns in a table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which contains the following rows :

```
╔══════════╦═══════════╦════════╗
║ PK_VALUE ║ RATING_ID ║ RATING ║
╠══════════╬═══════════╬════════╣
║       11 ║         1 ║     90 ║
║       11 ║         2 ║     80 ║
║       11 ║         3 ║     90 ║
║       12 ║         1 ║     90 ║
║       12 ║         2 ║     80 ║
║       12 ║         3 ║     90 ║
╚══════════╩═══════════╩════════╝
```

I want the above table as :

```
╔══════════╦════════════╦════════════╦════════════╗
║ PK_VALUE ║ RATING_ID1 ║ RATING_ID2 ║ RATING_ID3 ║
╠══════════╬════════════╬════════════╬════════════╣
║       11 ║         90 ║         80 ║         90 ║
║       12 ║         90 ║         80 ║         90 ║
╚══════════╩════════════╩════════════╩════════════╝
```

I tried some of the suggestions I found within a Google search, but it shows we have to insert into a table. I am not sure about this. Any suggestions welcome...

`I have uploaded the screenshots related to my doubt..`[image: image of the result query before what i use to get..]

`In this image we can see two review ID's for the same pk_value.. But I am receiving only one review ID after including your query..` [image: result after including your query..]

In the above   `How can I get result of both the review ID's???`

Comment: You've tried googling but have you tried [searching specifically this site](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mysql+pivot)?

Comment: Take a look at these links: [Dynamic pivot tables](http://buysql.com/mysql/14-how-to-automate-pivot-tables.html), [Automate pivot table queries](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#523).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `CASE` and `MAX`

```
SELECT  pk_value,
        MAX(CASE WHEN rating_ID = 1 THEN rating ELSE NULL END) AS r1,
        MAX(CASE WHEN rating_ID = 2 THEN rating ELSE NULL END) AS r2,
        MAX(CASE WHEN rating_ID = 3 THEN rating ELSE NULL END) AS r3
FROM    tableName
GROUP   BY pk_value
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/16164/2)

Otherwise, if you have unknown number of `Rating_ID` and you don't want to constantly updated the query, a `Dynamic SQL` is recommended,

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'MAX(CASE WHEN rating_ID = ',
      rating_id,
      ' then rating ELSE NULL end) AS `rating_id', rating_id, '`')
  ) INTO @sql
FROM TableName;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT  pk_value, ', @sql, ' 
                   FROM    tableName
                   GROUP   BY pk_value');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/16164/14)
- [SQLFiddle Demo (added new rating_id)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e32de/1)

both the query above have the same result,

```
╔══════════╦════════════╦════════════╦════════════╗
║ PK_VALUE ║ RATING_ID1 ║ RATING_ID2 ║ RATING_ID3 ║
╠══════════╬════════════╬════════════╬════════════╣
║       11 ║         90 ║         80 ║         90 ║
║       12 ║         90 ║         80 ║         90 ║
╚══════════╩════════════╩════════════╩════════════╝
```

Comment: Thank u sir... upto now I havent known about this SQL Fiddle.. this is really beautiful for developers.. Thank u once again..

Comment: You have edited my question and added table structure to the numbers.. I would like to know how can we do that??

Comment: sir a problem.. It is returning only one row of a table. if we have two or more pk values it is not displaing rest of them..

Comment: @PavanKumar give mi some sample data `:D` so we can fix it.

Comment: I have edited my question and includeed images to give more information regarding to my requirement..

Comment: the original query was grouping with `pk_value`. try `GROUP BY pk_value,review_id`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23184/discussion-between-pavankumar-and-jw)